# Two instances of google talk on startup

Tags: boot, google-talk, multiple-instances

I started two instances of gtalk. Each of them uses different gmail account. Used /nomutex parameter in target path.

At the moment after reboot only one instance is loaded.

How can I start two instances of gtalk on startup on windows 7 so that each uses different account?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily log into multiple accounts with one instance of Pidgin and run that at startup. It's what I ended up doing when I started having to log into both a gmail and a google talk for apps account.

Comment: Pidgin doesn't support all features of gtalk I need.

Comment: @Trac3, what features of Gtalk does Pidgin lack which you want? It's possible that the features you seek may be available as a plugin or through some feature you haven't seen before.